# time overflow mins secs and hours

Tags: java, string, int, overflow, joptionpane

im in need of some code to stop my current code
producing negative numbers if the start INTs are larger than the End INTs
Im aware there is a lot of code here i have commented out the bit i need help with (about half way down) but i wanted to provide it all so you ca complie and run to se what im struggling with

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class race {
 public static void main(String[] args) {


       System.out.println("Course  Start time  End time  Gender  Total time    Name");

  int count = 1;
    while (count<7){
        count++;
  System.out.println( "");
     String colour = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                 "Competitor Enter your course colour first letter" );

     String Starth = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "Competitor Enter your Start time (hours)" );
                     int  Starthour=Integer.parseInt(Starth);          

     String Startm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Competitor Enter your Start time (mins)" );
                    int  Startmin=Integer.parseInt(Startm);

     String Starts = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
            "Competitor Enter your Start time (secs)" ) ;
                    int Startsec=Integer.parseInt(Starts); 

 String  Endh = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "Competitor Enter your End time (hours)" );
                     int  Endhour=Integer.parseInt(Endh);

     String Endm = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "Competitor Enter your End Time (mins)" );
                     int Endmin=Integer.parseInt(Endm);    

     String Ends = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "Competitor Enter your End Time (secs)" );
                     int Endsec=Integer.parseInt(Ends);    

     String sex = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "Male or Female (M/F)" );

     String Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
             "Competitor Enter your Full Name (Joe Bloggs)" );


             int Timeh = (Endhour - Starthour); 
             int Timem = (Endmin - Startmin);
             int Times = (Endsec - Startsec);
```

//so here i need code so that if i take endsec  e.g50 away from startsec                            e.g54 Times wont print out -4, rather it will take one of Timem and print Times as 56//

```
 System.out.print(colour);
 System.out.print("     ");
 System.out.print( String.format("%02d",Starthour));
 System.out.print( ":");
 System.out.print( String.format("%02d",Startmin));
 System.out.print( ":");
 System.out.print( String.format("%02d",Startsec));
 System.out.print( "   ");
 System.out.print( String.format("%02d",Endhour));
 System.out.print( ":");
 System.out.print( String.format("%02d",Endmin));
 System.out.print( ":");
 System.out.print( String.format("%02d",Endsec)); 
 System.out.print("      "+sex);
 System.out.print("      "+Timeh);
 System.out.print(":");
 System.out.print(""+Timem);
 System.out.print(":");
 System.out.print(""+Times);
 System.out.print("     "+Name);

 }// end while
 }
  }
```

Comment: You are using classes from Swing off of the EDT. This is in violation of Swing's threading policy and **will** case seemingly random and inexplicable bugs and may result in death. Read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) very carefully before doing any further Swing programming.

Comment: Please try to follow the standard Java code conventions like method and variable names with small letters while capitalizing class names for sake of better readability.

Comment: Further, always stick to Java naming conventions. Using `camelCase` for variables and `PascalCase` **only** for classes. Your code is very difficult to read because not adhering to code conventions makes it hard to tell at a glance what's going on. It also messes up the syntax highlighting here on SO.